# How to use curl to get web server type?

Tags: bash, shell, curl

Here's some of the lines from my shell script:

```
curl -I --connect-timeout 60 google.com|grep "Server:" >> 1000-server.txt
curl -I --connect-timeout 60 yahoo.com|grep "Server:" >> 1000-server.txt
curl -I --connect-timeout 60 bing.com|grep "Server:" >> 1000-server.txt
```

My script is getting the web server type correctly in most cases:

```
Server: gws
Server: ATS
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
```

However, if the `curl` connection times out or get an error, it doesn't output any message.  Also, if for some reason `grep` doesn't find anything, it doesn't output any error message.

If `curl` or `grep` fails, is there any way to output an error message that just says something like `"ERROR: NOT FOUND"`?

Sorry if this is a newbie questions, just can't figure it out...

Answer (score 1):

```
curl -I --connect-timeout 60 google.com|grep "Server:" >> 1000-server.txt || echo ERROR | tee -a 1000-server.txt
```

The `curl ... | grep ...` command will return false if grep doesn't find the string. In that case, the `|| echo ERROR | tee -a 1000-server.txt` will execute.

The output from echo is piped into *tee*, which, in turn, will append (-a) the output to the file **1000-server.txt** also printing the same output to STDOUT.

Comment: That almost seems to do it, but it's not echoing "ERROR" to `1000-server.txt`, it just displays it in terminal.

Comment: Hi, can you explain your answer a bit? Popped up in the review queue, as code-only answers tend to. Thanks!